# BAD Command Argument Error while storing email message with Hebrew attachment names

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, email, imap

I'm making a Mail Router service that takes e-mail messages from one mailbox and moves them to another mailbox.
I use the `S22.Imap` library to do so.

When storing messages with attachment with Hebrew names in them I get `xm002 BAD Command Argument Error`. I noticed the name encoding for the message is `null`, and that the encoding in the content disposition property is `utf-8`.

I did encounter cases where attachments where able to work with Hebrew names, but the encoding was `windows-1255`. I tried changing the name encoding to that, but the didn't work, maybe because the content disposition encoding was still `utf-8`.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no way for me to diagnose the problem without more information, but S22.Imap is definitely broken when it comes to encoding messages properly and this is likely leading to a miscalculation of the message size when appending it to the folder.

I would highly recommend using my [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library instead as it does not suffer from these sorts of problems.

Comment: Sounds great! Does it have a similar method to StoreMessage?

Comment: It has an `Append()` on the `ImapFolder` class. The README on the GitHub page has some docs that will get you started and http://www.mimekit.org/docs has full API documentation.